# Get the map from controller using ajax call in spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am calling the controller from a plane jsp page with out form submit using ajax and I want to return a hashmap from controller to the jsp page which i can iterate to show the values of hashmap.

If I am sending a message in the response , I can get that in the ajax function inside success: but how to get the whole map. Because if you even set in the request attribute you can't get that in the jsp page.Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [@ResponseBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) annotation on your controller's method. For e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourAjaxRequestUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> performOperation(@RequestParam("someParam") String someParam) {

    //Do something

    return Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("yourObject", yourObject);
}
```

This will return you an object in JSON format, all objects in your map then can be accessed via javascript.

Comment: Sir can you please tell how to get them in ajax call of JQuery... Also plz tell me if that map has multiple key,value pairs then returning the map will return all the entries as well? If it is possible then how to get that value in Jquery. if my map has an entry like `("key", value)` where `value` is an Object. then how can I access that value in my Jquery..

Kindly reply me sir, I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing your server-side code with your client-side code. AJAX is client side, JSPs are server side. You just cannot pass data between the two.

When you're making your AJAX call, the JSP has already finished execution, and the markup it produced is there in the browser, including your AJAX code.

If your Spring Controller is returning JSON (maybe you're representing your Map as a JavaScript associative array), then you can use jQuery to iterate over that array and create dynamic HTML elements according to its contents.